# Application of Reflection Principle for Holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic on $D'(0,1)=\{0<|z|<1\}$ and $f$ is continuous and real valued on $\{|z|=1\}.$ Show $f$ can be extended to $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ such that $f(z)= \overline{f(1/\overline{z})}, \forall z \neq 0.$

My attempt: $f=u+iv=u$ on $\{|z|=1\}.$ By Max/Min Principle for Harmonic functions, $v \equiv 0$ in $D^{\prime}(0,1) \ $ and so $f \equiv $ constant  in $D'(0,1).$ By Identity Theorem, $f \equiv$ constant in $\mathbb{C} \  ?$ I suspect I have wrongly applied the Max/Min Principle because $f$ is not necessarily continuous on boundary of $D^{\prime}(0,1) \ ?$

I'm trying to make use the following theorem:

> Let $\Omega$ be a region which is symmetric wrt to real axis and define $\Omega^+, \Omega^{-}$ and $L$ as intersection of $\Omega$ with upper half plane, lower half plane and real axis respectively. If $f$ is continuous on $\Omega^+ \cup L$  which is analytic on $\Omega^+$ and real on $L,$ then $f$ can be uniquely extended to holomorphic $F$ on all of $\Omega$ such that $F(z)=f(z), z \in \Omega^+ \cup L; F(z)= \ \overline{f(\overline{z})}, z \in \Omega^-.$

Could anyone advise please? Thank you.

Comment: $u$ and $v$ are not defined in $0$, so you can't apply the maximum principle to deduce that $v\equiv 0$ from its vanishing on $\lvert z\rvert = 1$. It can be unbounded at $0$.

Comment: Let $Tz = \frac{z-i}{z+i}$. What do you know about $f\circ T$?

Comment: $f \circ T : \mathbb{H}-\{i\}$ is a holomorphic map?

Comment: And, what about its behaviour at the real axis?

Comment: $T$ maps real axis to boundary of the unit disk and $f$ maps those boundary points into $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: Right. So, what does the theorem tell you?

Comment: $f \circ T (z) = \overline {f \circ T (\overline {z})},$ where $z$ lies on $L.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Let
$$
g(z)=f\left(\frac{z-i}{1-iz}\right).
$$
Then $g$ takes real values on the real axis, and it is analytic in the upper half plane.

Use Schwarz Reflection for $g$, and then use the inverse transformation:

$$f(z)=g\left(\frac{z+i}{1+iz}\right).$$